# Difference line box between empty inline and inline-block element

Tags: html, css

My understanding is that in an inline formatting context, line box stacks vertically. And the height of the container box is the distance from the top edge of the topmost line box to the bottom edge of the bottommost line box.

But what happens if the inline element and inline-block element is empty? I guess that no line box will be created in both cases and the container height would be 0.

However the empty inline-block element puzzles. Because its container has a positive height which equals to the line height. It really creates a line box!

Why the empty inline-block element creates a line box, but the empty inline element does not?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <div style="background:red">
    <span style="display:inline-block"></span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is the `div` that has height. Not — the `span`.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, this statement from [CSS 2.2 Section 9.4.2 Inline formatting contexts](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#inline-formatting)

> Line boxes are created as needed to hold inline-level content within an inline formatting context. Line boxes that contain no text, no preserved white space, no inline elements with non-zero margins, padding, or borders, and no other in-flow content (such as images, **inline blocks** or inline tables), and do not end with a preserved newline must be treated as zero-height line boxes for the purposes of determining the positions of any elements inside of them, and must be treated as not existing for any other purpose.

So inline-blocks explicitly stop the line containing them from being treated as zero height or not existing.

Answer (score 0):

When you use display: inline it means the content will be in the same line(continuation) as whatever is before and after.

When you use display:inline-block, it begins the display in a new line followed by new content.

Here is a link for examples 
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Answer (score 0):

Elements with `display: inline-block` create a new block and the element will naturally expand to fill the container. Inline elements don't have a `width` or `height` property so they don't have any height or width unless there's some content inside it.

Comment: What is the "new block"? The inline-block `span` box or some anonymous box that wraps the inline-block? The Chrome devtool shows that the span box size is 0x0.